# Importing an STL and adding it to a project

Tags: import, 3d-printing

I am creating a modern Queens Guard bandsman/lady. Can I import an stl file of an instrument for the musician, get the muso to hold it and scale it down to size, then save the muso with the instrument as a completed project ready to 3D print?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Blender supports STL format and you can definitely make stuff for 3D printing in Blender. A model made in Blender will be ready for printing in a sense that it will be ready to import into some slicer software of your choice that makes an instruction file for your printer's hardware like for example a .gcode file if it's an FDM printer.